# Nuances between "... бы ... ни ..." and "неважно, ..."

Tags: словоупотребление

> Какое **бы** положение ты **ни** занимал в обществе, ...
>
> **Неважно**, какое положение занимаешь в обществе, ...
>
> **Не важно**, какое положение занимаешь в обществе, ...

I tend to use these subordinate structures almost interchangeably to express the idea of "no matter ...", but I wonder if and how they are nuanced.

Comment: **не важно** is incorrect since here we're dealing with the adverb **неважно**, and not with a negated adjective **важно**, as far as nuances are concerned, in my opinion conditional mood is more idiomatic

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка guess it would be worthy to give real example when it would had been legit, to give a real gist of things rather than abstract formal definition. So, that would be legit in phrases like "Не то важно, какое положение...., а как тебя запомнят дети" or like "Не важно, а очень важно, какое положение...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure one can find big nuances here. These structures seem  to be more functional and auxiliary, they express the idea 'no matter', but their lexical content is of less importance. However, one could think of *неважно* as stressing that it really 'doesn't matter', it seems closer to the idea of 'unimportance' (and it expresses it lexically), whereas *бы - ни*- doesn't explicitly say it's unimportant, it sounds more neutral and lacks that categorical 'unimportance' (which is rather expressed grammatically than lexically here).

Comment: as a native speaker I fully confirm this. the only thing I have to tell here is that the `"Неважно, какое положение занимаешь в обществе!"` option can be used as a complete phrase to accentuate it more (if the second part of phrase is clear by context).

Answer (score 0):

Неважно, какое положение занимаешь в обществе - в этом случае "неважно" пишется ВСЕГДА слитно. Последний вариант с раздельным правописанием неверный.

Однако если будет идти конструкция "ничуть не важно", "совсем не важно", "отнюдь не важно", то здесь пишется раздельно.

Comment: не всегда, но как правило, если человек задал вопрос на английском - лучше на английском и ответить.